# My models collection field is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm using an ASP.NET MVC web application to make Back-Ups of my VSTS Server.

My DB has a bunch of nested tables, in this case, I am accessing a table called "Project". One of its fields is an ICollection with Backup being yet another table in my DB / model in my MVC. The projects load just fine in the View that is created with one of the standard Controller templates, the field ICollection, however, is always null, even though there are definitely "Backups" in my DB.

This is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Backup_Tool.Models.Site>

@functions{
    public string GetLatest(Backup_Tool.Models.Project projekt)
    {
        if (projekt.Backup == null)
            return "( - )";
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-500);
        foreach (var back in projekt.Backup)
        {
            if (back.CreationTime > time)
                time = back.CreationTime;
        }
        return $"{time.ToShortDateString()}";
    } }
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Uri)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
        </td>
        <td>
            @foreach (var project in item.Projects)
            {
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => project.Name)</p>
                <i>@GetLatest(project)</i>




            }
        </td>
```

Do I need to add the Backup Model at the top as well? Actually load the Backup, using a DB Context?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without your entity classes, but most likely, you neglected to add the `virtual` keyword to your collection property, and also failed to eagerly load it.

The `virtual` keyword is necessary for Entity Framework's lazy-loading functionality. EF actually creates a proxy class that inherits from your entity class and then overrides navigation properties to add lazy-loading logic. If the property is not virtual, it cannot override it, and therefore cannot add the necessary lazy-loading logic.

However, it's far better to just eagerly load the collection, rather than relying on lazy-loading. While lazy-loading is easy, it's also inefficient and often leads to logical errors that are not obvious. For example, if you do something like this, you'll raise an exception:

```
 using (var context = new MyDbContext())
 {
     var foo = context.Foos.ToList();
 }

 foreach (var bar in foo.Bars) // where `Bars` is a lazy-loaded collection
 {
     ...
 }
```

At the point of the `foreach` the context has already been disposed, so when EF attempts to load the collection in order to iterate over it, it will fail. If you just came upon this code, it's not obvious where the error is, which is a pretty big deal if you want maintainable code.

Anyways, in order to eagerly load the collection, simply use `Include` in your initial query. For example:

```
var project = context.Projects.Include(m => m.Backups).SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == projectId);
```

Note, you must use something like `SingleOrDefault`, rather than `Find`. `Find` attempts to load the entity from the context cache first before hitting the database, so the logic is incompatible with joining in other entities.

Finally, your `GetLatest` function is both inefficient and superfluous. Simply use LINQ's `Max` function:

```
@foreach (var project in item.Projects)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(m => project.Name)</p>
    <i>@(project.Backups.Max(m => m.CreationTime).ToShortDateString())</i>
}
```

Also, avoid string interpolation when you're just returning a value as-is. For example, this code:

```
return $"{time.ToShortDateString()}";
```

Should simple be:

```
return time.ToShortDateString();
```

The end result is the same, but you're only adding one string to the heap instead of two. While that's a fairly minor thing, little inefficiencies like this can add up into big problems in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the Max() Function, wasn't sure it would work for DateTime ...